# unmounted dev/sda1 with root filesystem is not working out

Tags: windows-7

Can you please help me how to unmount dev/sda1 manually? i tried sudo command in terminal but it didn't work.

When i tried, it says.
device is busy.
in some cases useful info about processes that use the device is found by lsof(08) or fuser(1)

So what i should do next? please help me.

Comment: does this partition contains something like /boot or /home, or just data, if so is there an app that is using one of the files on that partition

Comment: so should i delete all the files in this partition?

Comment: no, i asked you to know what data is contained in that partition

Comment: ahhh,ok. yes, this partition containing that /boot/ home/ etc. what do i have to do?

Comment: why you tagged your question as "windows-7"

Comment: because i am installing windows7 but i cant coz of unmounted partition. that is why i'm doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot unmount the partition of the system you're running. If you want to modify the partition (like shrinking it), you have to boot a live USB or live DVD and use gparted on your system partition.

Comment: do you know to to make live usb? can you please help me fix my problem. i know that i have to make live usb but i dont know to. please help me. thank you.

Comment: Install and use Unetbootin or use "Startup Disk Creator"

Comment: what file should i download when i am using "Startup disk Creator" do you have link? please?  thank you.

Comment: Any Ubuntu .iso from [the site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/)

Comment: But everytime i download the ubuntu.iso file with size 982mb, it'll say downloading complete even if it has only downloaded 200mb file. why this happened? the internet connection is stable and i tried it thrice. same thing "downloading complete" but it will never completed to its 982mb size.

Comment: Try using a download manager like "Downloadthemall" extension for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

based on the clarifications you provided, this partition is a system partition, so you can not unmount using umount, only the system is able to umount while shutting down!

for any non-system  partition, you can use Gparted (available in software center)
and choose the partition you want to unmount and right-click it then choose unmount

**NOTE** : gparted is a powerful software, it can make your system unusable if misused

**UPDATE**  use `umount -f /dev/sda1/`

Comment: yes! i already use gparted, i was advised to unmount manually. all i have to do is to replace the File System ext4 into ntfs to install windows7. do you know what should i do?

Comment: i tried umount -f /dev/sdai/ but still device or resource busy. how?